# Can subjunctive mood come after the adjective 'customary?'

Tags: verbs, subjunctive-mood

It's from a standard test and they do not reveal their test item so I can't remember the exact sentence itself but it was like as follows.

It is customary that the winner ________ a bottle of milk in the finish line.

I ruled out the 2 options, which contained past tense, and thought that most possible answers were either (a) drink or (b)is drinking. I thought this has to do with subjunctive mood and the answer would be 'drink' as the auxiliary verb should is being omitted. But I don't believe I saw the adjective 'customary' among the lists of adjectives that can precede a that-cluase containing subjunctive mood. So, I just want to check whether it's the case or I'm wrong.

Thank you so much for your opinion :)

Comment: Examples from google books - it is customary that a prebid conference be held. https://books.google.it/books?id=RhVFDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA455&dq=%22it+is+customary+that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHuq2e-qjpAhXksIsKHXKADxYQ6AEIPDAD#v=onepage&q=%22it%20is%20customary%20that%22&f=false - but in most cases the indicative is used. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20is%20customary%20that%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: It is customary that the winner __drink/s___a bottle of milk in the finish line. Or It is customary for the winner to drink a bottle of milk in the finish line.

Comment: @Hachi: In the U.S., *customary* usually takes the subjunctive in cases like this. Googling "customary that he is" versus "customary that he be", there were slightly more hits for *be*, and many of the hits for *is* were clearly either British or Indian. And lots of speakers of British or Indian English don't use the present subjunctive at all.

Comment: @PeterShor - yes, Il didn’t elaborate it into a full answer. Thanks for the details.